# How to sort records in a file using a stack, queue, or BST in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, stack, queue, binary-search-tree

If you have a .dat file with records such as:

```
805816899 Andrew
803975268 Bob
912684297 Jeff
123546789 Louis
751354687 Kevin
```

What would be the easiest data structure to use in order to sort the list by ID number and then write to screen? I figure a BST would make the most sense and be the most efficient, but a stack would be easier and faster when dealing with a small file such as this.

Also, how would you implement it?

Comment: For some reason this feel like a pedogogical question to me, so let me ask you: what ordering properties do stacks, queue and BST's have. What kind of access do you have to the data with those structures? What does this imply about the utility of them in a "put things in order" context?

Comment: Why u considering BST, BST is for searching purpose . U can just create array of structures and apply sorting algorithm like Quick/merge sorts,

Comment: For a stack, I'm given the usual functions, Push, Pop, IsEmpty. IsFull. And yea, I believe quick and mergesort is available. Since we went over it. It's standard in the library right, so I don't have to rewrite it

Comment: For small data, it really doesn't matter what you use. Just pass it to the built-in `sort` program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest was to sort them using a BST would be to put them in an `std::map<int, std::string>`. This is a self sorted data structure using a BST internally (although that isn't explicitly specified by the standard). If you do not want look-up, you can use an `std::set` of a user defined type instead (see next paragraph).

If you want to store them in a flat array-like structure, you could create a small struct to hold the information, store instances of it in an `std::vector`, and use a suitable comparison function in combination with `std::sort` to do the sorting.

BST:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
std::map<int, std::string> m;
m[805816899] = "Andrew";
m[803975268] = "Bob";
```

and so on.

array-like solution:

```
struct Foo 
{ 
  Foo(int ID, const std::string& name) : ID(ID), name(name) {}
  int ID; 
  std::string name;
};
// comparison for sorting
bool comp(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) { return lhs.ID < rhs.ID; }

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
....
std::vector<Foo> v;
v.push_back(Foo(805816899, "Andrew"));
v.push_back(Foo(803975268, "Bob"));
// add more entries
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
```

Comment: Isn't a std::vector inefficient for random access insertions needed during sorting?

Comment: I am not sure BST is required here..since user only wants sorting and not searching

Comment: Being an sophomore undergrad, we haven't even gone over vectors. Is there perhaps a simpler solution?

Comment: create array of structs which contain ID and name as fields and then apply quick sort on struct id integer fields

Comment: @EtienneCordonnier I wouldn't worry about any such inefficiencies. The performance of `std::vector` is actually pretty good in this respect, compared to fragmented data structures such as linked lists.

Comment: @user1787038 I cannot think of a solution simpler than using a vector. Of course, if you have an assignment and are supposed to implement this functionality, then using any of the stuff I have shown would defeat the purpose.

Comment: But isn't insertion at any position O(n) in a vector and O(1) in a linked list ? I guess the vector sort would be inefficient for a big data set.

Comment: @EtienneCordonnier But the actual operations in the O(n) are very fast, and with the list you have O(n) look-up. The advice these days is "use vector by default". I would only use list if I needed to be sure iterators remain valid throughout. See [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style).

Comment: See this link for an example for a comparison of sort on vectors and linked lists, list seems 5 times faster with n=1 million: 
http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque/
But I get your point.

Comment: @EtienneCordonnier noce blog, but probably irrelevant. There should be no random inserts going on during the sort.

Comment: Well, the blog is actually also comparing sorting algorithms (go down). But you're actually right, sorting on vector is faster than on a linked list when the individual elements are smaller than 1KB because of the memory overhead on the linked lists.

Comment: @EtienneCordonnier You wouldn't do *insertion* for sorting a vector you load it up linearly and then sort--the sort using *assignment* to swap cells.

Comment: @Alien01 BST's have an couple of interesting properties. They can be filled with n items in O(n log n) time and then read out *in order* in O(n) time. The result is that yes, there *is* a way to sort with them. It's not generally used because while the asymptotic performance is of the right order the multiplier is unnecessarily large.

Answer (score 0):

I think, a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is the easiest way to implement the whole sorting and it's O(n) if the length of the id is constant.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

class node {
  bool final;
  union {
    node *next[10];
    char *name;
  };
  node *get_at(int index)
  {
    assert(!final);
    return next[index] ? next[index] : (next[index] = new node);
  }

public:
  node() : final(false) { std::fill(next, next+10, (node*)0); }
  ~node() {
    if (final)
      delete name;
    else
      for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        delete next[i];
  }

  void insert(const char *id, std::string const& s)
  {
    if (*id) {
      get_at(*id - '0')->insert(id+1, s);
    } else {
      final=true;
      name = new char[s.size()+1]();
      std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), name);
    }
  }

  void print_all(std::ostream& os) const
  {
    if (final)
      os << name << '\n';
    else
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        if (next[i])
          next[i]->print_all(os);
  }
};

int main()
{
  node top;
  for (std::string id, name; std::cin >> id >> name;)
    top.insert(id.c_str(), name);
  top.print_all(std::cout);
}
```